# How to handle "mostly-static but editable" content in a Rails app?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, crud

I've got a Rails app hosted online, where the standard content has CRUD operations enabled, and multiple editors can create, edit and delete the content using controls in the views. This is working well.

There's also an About page, which contains content that mostly won't change. This is hard-coded in a view, and any changes require me to edit the view, then push the changes to the live site.

**I'd like to allow the editors to edit this content online, without requiring my involvement.**

Presumably the About page's content will need to be stored in the database, but it doesn't seem logical to enable the full CRUD operations on it. Eg, there will only be 1 About page, and it shouldn't be possible to delete it.

What is the preferred Rails approach for allowing the About page's mostly-static content to be editable online?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If all you want is to avoid allowing editors to delete your page, you can just avoid not  putting the delete action (delete, destroy) inside your views and controllers. However, you will need to enable the create, read and update actions (CRU) , as that really is the only way to update the site remotely, short of giving them access to your app directly and having them upload it directly on to your hosting server (not recommended).

I'm assuming you already have a functioning login/authentication system, so you would simply need to just extend that functionality to the about page, by requiring the editors to login and authenticate themselves, before being allowed to perform CRUD (without the delete, D) functions.

Note that even if you were to get rid of the delete function, they could delete the about page accidentally or on purpose by simply performing an update that has nothing inside of it. You should just to be safe be saving your webpages to some sort of version control software (i.e.: Git), so that even in an event where your information gets lost, a previous backup can be used to restore your website to a previous state.

Comment: Thanks, that's pretty much what I assumed but I wasn't sure if there is a "rails way" to do it.